# Redis Sentinel Authentication

Tags: redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I have 3 Servers with Redis and Sentinel Running. 
All instances have in the configuration

```
requirepass XXX
masterauth XXX
```

I can connect with redis-cli to the redis server but if I try to connect to the sentinel I can not authenticate.

```
root@ip-:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# redis-cli -p 26379
127.0.0.1:26379> AUTH xxx
(error) ERR unknown command 'AUTH'
127.0.0.1:26379>
```

If I use the same command but with the redis port it works.

Thanks
best

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to setup auth for sentinels, too. I mean `requirepass=<password>` in sentinel.conf. More info on this [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3279) and [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3329). Be careful, as not every client supports this setup.

Also, you need to set `sentinel auth-pass <master-name> <password>` in that file, in order for the sentinels to be able to administrate secured redis servers. (But I'm guessing you already did that).

Comment: Don't sentinels also have to talk to each other? Do they just assume they're all using the same password?

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica here's the commit that enabled authentication for sentinels: https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/fa675256c127963c74ea68f8bab22ef105bada02. If you see the description, it says: "every Sentinel will try to
authenticate with other sentinels using the same password it is
configured to accept clients with."

Comment: BEWARE to put the config line `sentinel auth-pass <master-name> <password>` after the master declaration `sentinel monitor <master-name> ...`